# Is it good practice to have a big structure that contains multiple objects of other structures?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, esp32

I'm making a code in PlatformIO for ESP32, and I came across a way of making structures that I'm not sure would be advantageous for the microcontroller, but sure seems to make my life a lot easier. Here's an example:

```cpp
struct Error 
{
    bool lowBattery;
    bool commTimeout;
};

struct User
{
    uint8_t id;
    bool theme;
    uint8_t pass[4];
};

struct Device
{
    User user;
    Error error;
    uint8_t taskCode;
    uint8_t taskName[20];
} device;
```

In this example, I'm making objects of `User` and `Error` in `Device` structure, and then making an object called `device`. This way, I'm able to manage all of my data through this singular object, and I can access all elements by `device.error.lowVoltage`, giving additional context when I'm building code around this structure. From what I've read about structures, this might make the total size of a single object very large, to the point that my microcontroller might not be able to handle it. This is an example; my use case will have even larger structures. So far, I've not come across any glaring issue, but it will a lot of unnecessary changes if I get an error related to this approach in the future.

So, am I being unnecessarily paranoid? What can go wrong with this approach? Is there another way I can make managing data easier?

Comment: Design is often Opinion Based which is off-topic for SO.  Is there anyway you can ask the question so that it does not require an opinion based answer?

Comment: It shouldn't make much of a difference if you pack all data into one single large object (which is what I usually do, too, in comparable situations) or if you have a bunch of smaller objects that sum up in size to the same – unless you store all values in individual global variables and sort them by size to reduce number of padding bytes to a minimum...

Comment: This approach might waste some memory because of padding. How many devices do you need to handle (tens, hundreds, thousands?). What is the memory size of your ESP32 board?

Comment: Note that you might compress multiple booleans into one single byte; unless you intend to serialise the data bit-fields might be a nice approach for.

Comment: In general, this is a variation on the composition *vs* association question.  Are a `User` and an `Error` conceptually *part of* a `Device`?  Then it makes perfect sense for `Device` to have members of those types.  Or are `User`s (for example) conceptually independent of `Device`s?  Especially, could the same `User` be associated with more than one `Device`?  Then it probably makes more sense for a `Device` to contain a *pointer* to a `User` that is managed separately, if even that.

Comment: If that data has to exist in any case, placing it into a single structure will make no difference.  So long as you are not passing such structures by copy rather than reference, or creating instances where not all the data is required.  The structure itself is not the problem.  It is more a question of cohesiveness - do those objects belong together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I've read about structures, this might make the total size of a single object very large, to the point that my microcontroller might not be able to handle it.

Unlikely, although optimizing structs for alignment in order to reduce padding is common practice during code review. In your specific example there isn't much to do since all members likely boil down to 1 byte types. In general you would try to keep things aligned with 32 bits.

> to the point that my microcontroller might not be able to handle it

These ESP32 things they have *huge* RAM memory of some 320kib so I wouldn't worry about a few bytes here and there. If you somehow manage to run out of RAM despite that, then struct padding is probably the least of your problems. Just keep in mind not to allocate huge arrays or structs on the stack.

> What can go wrong with this approach?

The only thing that can go from is if you attempt to serialize/deserialize these structs for sending over a serial bus etc, in which case you have to consider alignment and padding (and endianess).

> Is there another way I can make managing data easier?

Focus on writing readable, maintainable code, with unambiguous type names and variable names. `Device` is for example a god-awfully poorly picked type name.

It makes perfect sense to put data that belongs together in the same struct. It doesn't make sense to put unrelated data in the same struct. Common sense will get you very far here.